# How to hide amp banner?

Tags: amp-html

The amp banner with its unnecessary close button takes up 10% of the screen which is ridiculous on a space-constrained device. Is there a way to hide it?[image]

Comment: Can you post a code snippet on how you implemented the [`amp-app-banner`](https://www.ampproject.org/ar/docs/reference/components/amp-app-banner)?

Comment: That isn't an app banner its the default banner that appears on all amp pages.